# Regex to match this pattern

Tags: java, regex

i have parsed some text files using stanford nlp from that output i need to extract text which matches below pattern

```
open bracket followed by NP or NNP or NNS etc
```

Input string

```
(NP (DT the) (NNP sample) (NN program))
```

result string

```
the ) sample ) program )
```

I have tried the below regex but it's not matching my required pattern

```
test.replaceAll("//(//NP|//(//JJ|//(//NNS|//(//NNP|//(//NN|//(//DT|//(//CD|//(//FW|//(//WHNP|//(//WDT|//(//VBN|//(//PRP", "")
```

Comment: Whats with all the slashes?

Comment: @Vulcan they look backwards to me.

Comment: You are using the wrong `slash` to escape, use `\` instead of `/`

Comment: can i use like this \\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"\\(NP|\\(JJ|\\(NNS|\\(NNP|\\(NN|\\(DT|\\(CD|\\(FW|\\(WHNP|\\(WDT|\\(VBN|\\(PRP"`

Slashes are wrong. Use `\\` instead of `/`

Comment: You have added one extra slash before NN When i remove that its working \\(NP|\\(JJ|\\(NNS|\\(NNP|\\(NN|\\(DT|\\(CD|\\(FW|\\(WHNP|\\(WDT|\\(VBN|\\(PRP"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you have all those slashes in there.

Try this:

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\((NP|JJ|NNS|NNP|NN|DT|CD|FW|WHNP|WDT|VBN|PRP)", "");
```

Here's a [live demo](https://ideone.com/o27Xn3) of this code working (correctly).

Comment: Getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1
(
 ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Pattern.java:1571)

Comment: I have tested this, by copy-pasting so there's no chance of a transcription error, and it works perfectly.